# Downloading typescript definition file in Visual Studio Code from behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Mac from behind a corporate proxy, and when I use feature in the IDE to add the reference to the typescript definition, it adds the `/// reference path`, but the `d.ts` file fails to download. I'm left with on error on the `/// reference path` that says `file not found`.

I tried when not behind the corporate proxy and it works flawlessly so I'm pretty certain it's a proxy issue.  My problem is that I don't see anyway to specifically add proxy settings in VS Code.  I also searched through their docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/) and don't see anything on network settings in general.

My OS network proxy settings are correct as other applications work properly.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **workaround** that i use:

> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

It's a npm package for typescript definitions and with it i can define my coporate proxy in a '.tsdrc' file like this:

```js
// .tsdrc
{
    "proxy": "http://<proxy_user>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>"
}
```

The use of terminal/command line in addition to VS Code is a little bit nasty. But it works.

Here is an example workflow for initalising a new project with nodejs and angularjs:

```
$ tsd init
$ tsd install node -s
$ tsd install angular -s
```

Comment: It's only a little nasty, but compared to what I was doing, this is way better. tsd installed and worked for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: How exactly do you create this file? Windows doesn't allow for empty file names, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting the proxy configuration property directly on tsd npm module config file (**settings.json**), under directory:

> *{YOUR_GLOBAL_NPM_REPOSITORY}*/lib/node_modules/tsd/conf/

There, at the beginning of the file, there is a **proxy** property with *null* assigned to it. Use your prefered editor (I used command line *vim*) to set your proxy.

```
{
     "proxy": "<your-proxy-url>:<proxy-port-num>",
     .
     .
     .
}
```

For me, just saving the file and restarting VS Code did the trick. No need to  manually install anything.

hope it helps!